# Celery with AWS SQS queue suddenly cannot connect

Tags: celery, amazon-sqs

For about a year now this has worked problem-free, but seemingly suddenly stopped working this past week or two, and I'm not sure where to look.

To start celery I just run this command:

```
PYTHONPATH=[path to project]:. celery -A update.tasks worker -Q update_local --concurrency 2 -E
```

On AWS I have an SQS setup named `update_local`.

In the celery config.py file I have `BROKER_URL = sqs://[AWS:KEYS]@` for the account that has the `update_local` SQS queue.

When I run it now, I get:

```
[2020-03-10 22:26:23,789: ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Cannot connect to amqp://guest:**@127.0.0.1:5672//: [Errno 61] Connection refused.
Trying again in 2.00 seconds...
```

Over and over again.

I was able to get it to run error free, but I have to specify the config file with the `--config` flag. Not sure why it no longer finds the file by itself.

Comment: Are you using the same virtual environment as before, with all the same packages? Did you modify the name of the config file?

Comment: getting same problem , how can i resolve it ?

Comment: @RaviBhushan I'm still not sure what caused the sudden change, but the issue was resolved by moving the config file.

Comment: i have got solution, broker url was pick up from setting.py, i have fixed in celery.py